# Access a team project portal

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I want to allow some users  to access a team project portal, so  I give them read permission in sharepoint manage centre. But, I found that these accounts can access team project portal only on service, when logged in client, they're forbided.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the default account of vs2010 is server\administrator, so I gave the account some permission, then it's ok.